# Comparing the 'email' field and delete duplicates in Google Sheets corresponding to the duplicate email columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using this code sample that is on the Google Apps Script site which removes the duplicates in the sheet but I need some help modifying this to my needs.

This is what my data looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWhgp.png

The column headers are: Time, Name, Email, Contact, Stream and College Name. Now, I want to delete the duplicate rows comparing the email IDs of each row.

The sample code that I'm using is

```
/**
 * Removes duplicate rows from the current sheet.
 */
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (j in newData) {
      if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Please help me fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by just changing this:

```
 if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
    duplicate = true;
```

to

this:

```
 if(row[1] == newData[j][1] && row[2] == newData[j][2]){
    duplicate = true;
  }
```